# Как правильно писать "o'kаy"?

Tags: орфография, лексика, заимствования, апостроф

В английском пишется через апостроф, насколько я знаю. А как правильно это писать по-русски?

Comment: Надо писать "океюшки". Так попатриотичней будет!  )))

Comment: >В английском пишется через апостроф, насколько я знаю.

По англ. также иногда пишут слитно *okay* или *okey*. Про *ОК* уже написали ниже. По-русски тоже иногда пишут *окей* или *ОК*.

Comment: Посмотрел в англ. Викисловарь, для верности. Вы будете удивляться, но там под заголовком **Альтернативные формы** НЕТ варианта с апострофом! (в русском словаре есть). Нет **o'key**.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/okay

Comment: Вики в любом его проявлении нельзя импользовать как источник знаний. Только информации о них.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

О'кей и о-кей. Более употребительное - о'кей.

Answer (score 1):

Язык общения в инете вполне дапускает ОК. Об интернет-языке было что-то на грамоте.ру. Сейчас некогда искать.)))

Comment: из двух миллионов следует, что вы не могли не видеть, как утверждаете,ни разу.

Comment: Вы с кем общаетесь? Если со мной, то я и вас не вижу. Что из этого следет?!

Answer (score 0):

Ни разу не видел ОК написанным иначе.
В английском, разумеется. В русском  обычно тоже пишу именно так.

Comment: Наберите хотя бы в Яндексе, увидите 2 млн. ответов. Толковые словари и орфографические словари дают оба варианта (или один из названных Соан). Но ни один не дает варианта ОК.

Comment: Если Вы так пишете, то это не значит, что Вы пишете правильно. Вопрос ведь стоял о том, как НАДО писать, а не как Вы именно пишете.

Comment: Виктор1799, пожалуста не припысывакйтн мне ни явно, ни неявно логику типав "если я пишу, то это правильно". Я этим не страждаю. 

>Наберите хотя бы в Яндексе, увидите 2 млн. ответов  

Что именно набрать - и что следует их двух миллионов?!
наберите в гугле ОК - поличти е три с половиной **миллиарда** ответов.

>Но ни один не дает варианта ОК.  

Допустим, хотя не уверен. Что из этого следует? Только то, что надо смотреть словари аббревиатур. Другое дело, что достоверное неизвестно, аббревиатура ли это или просто окказиональное образование... Но это другой разговор.

Answer (score 0):

А при чём тут "как в английском"? У нас пока ещё свой (пока он окончательно не превратился в американский суржик) язык, который, как ЛЮБОЙ язык мира, обладает суверенностью собственной грамматики, правил, закономерностей, устоявшихся обычаев и т.д. А ПРАВИЛЬНО писать - "АС", так как это безграмотное, как и многое другое у американцев, слово произошло от "all correct", т.е. сокращенно - "АС".